# spacemacs gui lagging on close while saving clipboard

Tags: clipboard, spacemacs

When closing spacemacs with `SPC q s` or `SPC q q`. Often the emacs GUI will display the message "Saving Clipboard to X Clipboard Manager". Then it will not close.

Interestingly, this does not occur when using terminal emacs `emacs -nw`.

The clipboard on my os is Xfce Clipman. I'm thinking perhaps the emacs is assuming there is a different clipboard and performing an inappropriate operation.

I'm not sure how to debug this, because emacs is frozen when this is happening. Any suggestions as to how I can resolve this issue?

[not responding while saving clipboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wccv.png)

Answer (score 2):

Had this same issue. [As seen in the Emacs documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html), you  can stop this by disabling interaction with the clipboard manager.

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard-manager nil)
```